# Undefined values using jQuery DataTable

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, datatables

I'm Using jQuery DataTable to expose data in table form; on the table, I have a button that opens a Bootstrap Modal to modify two of these value and I use Ajax to send modified values to a Spring Controller.

This was the first columns definition in the data table:

```
"columnDefs": [
                        {
                           "targets": [ 0 ],
                           "visible": false
                           //"searchable": false
                        }],

                "columns":  [
                    { "data": "id" },
                    { "data": "date" },
                    { "data": "type" },
                    { "data": "name" },
                    { "data": "user_name" },
                    { "data": "status" },
                    { "data": "closing_date" },
                    { "data": "info" },
                    { "data": "note" },
                    { "render": function ( data, type, full, meta ) {


                        return "<button type='button' class='btn btn-info btn-md' data-toggle='modal' data-id=\'" + data.id + "\' data-target='#myModal'> Edit </button>";

                    }
```

Cause I got, after loading the app,  the console error:

> "data is not defined"

I asked here on Stack and it was suggested to me to change the render function in:

```
{ "render": function ( data, type, full, meta ) {


                        return "<button type='button' class='btn btn-info btn-md' data-toggle='modal' data-id=\'" + full[0] + "\' data-target='#myModal'> Edit </button>";

                    }
```

Now I have not the data error but when I try to use the button and modify the data, I get this output:

```
Object { newnote: "aaa", newstatus: "closed", idevent: undefined } <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" data-dismiss="modal">
```

(please note that note and status are the variable that can be modified). Seeing in eclipse, I can note that the console error tells me, summing, that the id field is not passed to the controller.

Indeed, in the ajax function that I use to send data, that is:

```
$('#myModal').on('click', '.btn.btn-success', function(event) {
        var form = $('#updateeventsform');
        var formdata = form.serializeObject();
        formdata.idevent = $(this).data('id');
        console.log(formdata, this);
        event.preventDefault();

        $.ajax({
                url: "../updateevents.json",
                type: "post",
                data: formdata,
                success : function() {

                    console.log("Invio riuscito.");
                }

            });

        });
```

if I try to change `formdata.idevent = $(this).data('id');` with some numeric value, for example: `formdata.idevent = 1;` I can send perfectly the data to controller and they are changed with no problems.

So, the issue is that the render function cannot take the id properly and this causes the ajax function not be able to take it and pass the controller; I have decided so to examine this function and I got two results that I cannot understand.

The code that I put here is in a file named `eventsdetailsdatatable.js`; but, if I pass the mouse on the `full[0]` code, I got this message: Origin:

```
src/main/webapp/static/js/custom/firewalldatatable.js
```

This file is another data table definition, used for Firewall section. Why is this happening? Can depend on the structure of the app and how data are located in their folders?

The other strange things is that if I use, instead of `full[0]`, the previous form, `data.id`, passing the mouse on it I can read:

```
Returns:
service.$locale
Origin:
angular
Guess?:
true
See:
http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$locale
```

but...I'm not using Angular; again, why is this happening?

Summing, I have a render function that does not set the data-id value properly, does not recognize the use of data or full and tell me that these values have an origin that they may have not.

Any idea?

Comment: because your id is not defined, change data-id to id

Comment: So, are you suggesting me to change, in the button, data-id=\'" + data.id + "\' with id=\'" + data.id + "\' ?

Comment: sorry, that was just a quick seggust, don't do that, it does'nt matter as data is for keeping information,  can you see what is your value for  $(this).data('id'); in console., i think its not right, as you said, if you put number it works,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by myself. Speaking with a colleague, we suppose that, cause the modal has his activation button code on a file as string and the rest of code into another, this may take some problems. We don't know if thies hypotesis is correct, but starting from this assumption we formulate this solution:

1. we put a global variable `id_event` at the start of code;
2. in the render function, set this variable with the data.id value, without using the data-id field in the modal button, by onclick in the button:

   { "data": null, "render": function ( data, type, full, meta ) {

   ```
                       return "<button type='button' class='btn btn-info btn-md' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#myModal' onclick=\'id_event="+data.id+"\'> Edit </button>";

                   }
   ```
3. In the ajax function for sending data to Controller, set with IDnumber the formdata.idevent field:

   formdata.idevent = id_event; //add the event id to form data, after setting it with the IDnumber variabile

This made our code perfectly working.

Answer (score 2):

You have to define `data` as `null` (I believe you not want the button to be placed in the `note` column) :

```
...
{ "data": "note" },
{ "data": null,
  "render": function ( data, type, full, meta ) {
    return "<button type='button' class='btn btn-info btn-md' data-toggle='modal' data-id=\'" + full.id + "\' data-target='#myModal'> Edit </button>";
  }
}
```

and address `full` instead of `data`, i.e. `data-id=\'" + full.id + "\'`

---

`$(this).data('id');` is wrong. It is jQuerys own invention of storing variables on an element. Unless you have added `data-id` with `data()` specifically you cannot retrieve it with `data()`. Use `$(this).attr('data-id')` instead.

Comment: Tested, but I still have an undefined value; may depend from what I have on ajax function? I mean, may I modify also formdata.idevent = $(this).data('id')?
I add that if now I pass the mouse on full.id I can read service.$locale wit angular as origin.

Comment: Tested; with your second answer on attr, I have other issue but i got why. The problem is the this word; if I left $(this).attr('data-id'), i continue to get undefined value. But, if I put the button id, for exemple: $('#5').attr('data-id'); the code works. I cannot use the same id for all button of course, so i set the id of the button with full.id, i.e.: id=\'" + full.id + "\'.
Now, the question becames: how can I pass the IDs for the formdata.event? Or what I must use instead of $(this)?