# ASP.NET MVC Deleting row jquery datatables

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, datatables

I have a problem with Deleting, Editing row from jquery datatable, it keeps telling me this error

> the parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'id' of non-nullable type

I figure out that the problem being kind of passing the id, As when I put the id directly in Ajax code it works well

Here is my `Product` model:

```
public partial class Products
{

    public int ID { get; set; }

    // Other properties removed for brevity
}
```

And `delete` method in Controller

```
public ActionResult delete(int id)
{
      db.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;

      Products d = db.Products.Where(m => m.ID == id).FirstOrDefault<Products>();
      db.Products.Remove(d);
      db.SaveChanges();

      return Json("success", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Here is my `DataTable` row where `delete` button is situated.

```
 {
       "data": "id", "render": function (data) {
                     console.log(data);
                     return "<a class='btn btn-success' onclick=Editrow(" + data + ") style='margin-left:12px'><i class='glyphicon glyphicon-edit'></i> Edit Record<a/>  <a class='btn btn-danger' onclick=DeleteRow(" + data + ")><i class='glyphicon glyphicon-trash'></i> Delete<a/>";
 },
```

Here `data` is getting undefined.

Here is My Ajax code:

```
 function DeleteRow(id) {
            if (confirm("Are You sure to delete this record..?")) {
                $.ajax({

                    type: 'POST',
                    //url: "/Products/delete/" + id,
                    url: '@Url.Action("delete", "Products")/' + id,
                    datatype: 'JSON',
                    //data: JSON.stringify({ id: id }),
                    success: function (response) {
                        if (response == "success") {

                            alert("Data Deleted successfully..");
                            window.location.reload();
                            //$("#myModal").modal('hide');
                        }
                    },
                    error: function (msg) {
                        alert(msg.responseText);
                    }

                });
            }
        }
```

Note:- when I directly add the id I wanna delete in Ajax code like this,  it works well

```
url: '@Url.Action("delete", "Products")/' + 10,
```

Comment: Did you tried `data: { id: id }` and leave the `@Url.Action()` as-is? I didn't recommend using query strings or paths on `url`, instead I suggest to use `data` property setting.

Comment: I tried this but it shows me nothing and in *inspect/console* the button appear like this /onclick="DeleteRow(undefined)"/

Comment: By mentioning `DeleteRow(undefined)`, actually you're passing `'@Url.Action("delete", "Products")/' + undefined`, which parsed as null parameter and throwing non-nullable type exception afterwards. Where that `DeleteRow` function called?

Comment: In the button :-
`return "<a class='btn btn-danger' onclick=DeleteRow(" + data + ")><i class='glyphicon glyphicon-trash'></i> Delete<a/>";
`

Comment: @hazem Check that data value is not passing from button click.

Comment: I think it not as i mentioned before "that the problem being kind of passing the id", but i don't know why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make it as follows:

```
{
    "data": "ID", "render": function (data) { // <-- `ID` instead of `id`
                   return "<a class='btn btn-success' onclick=Editrow(" + data + ") style='margin-left:12px'><i class='glyphicon glyphicon-edit'></i> Edit Record<a/>  <a class='btn btn-danger' onclick=DeleteRow(" + data + ")><i class='glyphicon glyphicon-trash'></i> Delete<a/>";
},
```

Now it should work.

Comment: I tried two ways but still the same problem and I think it not passing at all as I mentioned before "that the problem being kind of passing the id", but I don't know why.

Comment: Thank you very much for helping, it works well and great now <3

Comment: @TanvirArjel, could you post your final solution here please so that people who come here can see what was the answer

Comment: Simply it was my fault as i wrote my "data": "id" and my tabel have "ID" so that ajax can't identify it,  and it should be as you said "data": "ID" like in my database tabel

Answer (score 0):

The `id` value passed into `onclick` event contains `undefined` because you're using `data` parameter which has `undefined` value. Try using `full` parameter of the `render` section function with ID column name as key (I assumed you won't put the button inside column definition which contains data):

```
// delete button column definition
{ "data": null,
  "render": function (data, type, full, meta) {
     return "<a class='btn btn-danger' onclick=\'DeleteRow(" + full['idcolumnnamehere'] + ")\'><i class='glyphicon glyphicon-trash'></i>Delete</a>";
  }
}
```

Then setup the AJAX call with ID as in example below:

```
function DeleteRow(id) {
    if (confirm("Are You sure to delete this record..?")) {
        $.ajax({
           type: 'POST',
           url: '@Url.Action("Delete", "Products")',
           data: { id: id },
           datatype: 'json',
           success: function (response) {
               // do something with response
           },
           error: function (msg) {
               alert(msg.responseText);
           }
       });
    }
}
```

As alternative if `full` parameter still won't work, use a global identifier and set its value using `data.id`, then use that identifier into AJAX callback which provided [in this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45433197/undefined-values-using-jquery-datatable).

**Note:**

Since you're using `POST` request, make sure your controller decorated with `[HttpPost]` attribute, and remove `JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet` because it only required for GET request:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Delete(int id)
{
    // delete record here
    return Json("success");
}
```

Comment: Thank you for helping, it was a mistake by mine as the answer above you showed, but your answer too had given me hints I didn't know before Thank you again.